# Google App Engine python datastore stub storing references?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I am trying to do a simple test of a model. I insert and retrieve the model and check all that data I inserted with is present. I expect this test to fail with a simple, blank model, but it passes. Is this a quirk of the testing framework that I have to live with? Can I set an option to prevent it from keeping refs to python objects?

In the following, I expect it to fail at line 30, but it does not. It fails at the ref comparison as I insists the refs be different and they are not..

```
import unittest
from google.appengine.ext import ndb
from google.appengine.ext import testbed


class Action(ndb.Model): pass

class ActionTestCase(unittest.TestCase):

  def setUp(self):
    # First, create an instance of the Testbed class.
    self.testbed = testbed.Testbed()
    # Then activate the testbed, which prepares the service stubs for use.
    self.testbed.activate()

    self.testbed.init_datastore_v3_stub()
    self.testbed.init_memcache_stub()


  def tearDown(self):
        self.testbed.deactivate()

  def testFetchRedirectAttribute(self):
    act = Action()
    act.attr = 'test phrase'
    act.put()

    self.assertEquals(1, len(Action.query().fetch(2)))
    fetched = Action.query().fetch(2)[0]
    self.assertEquals(fetched.attr, act.attr)
    self.assertTrue(act != fetched)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Comment: Can you explain why you think this should fail? As far as I can see, you put an Action entity, then get the same one back, so of course they are equal.

Comment: @DanielRoseman The attr field is not defined in the Model, so it should not be saved (I think). So the place where I fetch it and test it should fail. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Models are defined as being equal if all of their properties are equal. If you care about identity instead (you probably shouldn't...), then you can use `assertIs` in your test.

Comment: Ah, thanks for telling me about assertIs. I don't really care about references. I was just pointing out that the data store stub is not really serializing and de-serializing my object, so even if I had not added the 'attr' property to the model, it was showing up in the retrieved object.

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, storing refs is the behavior of stubs. However, for TDD purposes, we do need to check if a property is defined in the model. The simple way to do so is to use keyword argument. If I write the test as follows, then it fails as expected.

```
def testFetchRedirectAttribute(self):
    act = Action(attr='test phrase)
    act.put()
```

The solved my immediate problem of having a failing that that I could code against.